# npx hardhat run --network localhost .\scripts\2_seed-exchange.js

Tags: erc-20, hardhat

This is the error

```shell
PS C:\pr0\token-exchange> npx hardhat run --network localhost .\scripts\2_seed-exchange.js
Using chainId: 31337
Dapp Token fetched:  0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3

mETH Token fetched:  0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512

mDAI Token fetched:  0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0

Exchange fetched: 0xCf7Ed3AccA5a467e9e704C703E8D87F634fB0Fc9

Error: network does not support ENS (operation="getResolver", network="unknown", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=providers/5.7.2)
    at Logger.makeError (C:\pr0\token-exchange\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (C:\pr0\token-exchange\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.<anonymous> (C:\pr0\token-exchange\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\base-provider.ts:1989:20)
    at step (C:\pr0\token-exchange\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\base-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.next (C:\pr0\token-exchange\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\base-provider.js:29:53)
    at fulfilled (C:\pr0\token-exchange\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\base-provider.js:20:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  reason: 'network does not support ENS',
  code: 'UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION',
  operation: 'getResolver',
  network: 'unknown'
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the source code of the project, and other details like blockchain used?

Comment: Probably it's some missing/invalid argument but It's hard to pinpoint the exact issue without further context or source code. I think this might be helpful for you. [Error: network does not support ENS](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/1289)

Answer (score 0):

If you see this error, it almost always indicates you passed in a bad value to something that expected an address. If you are on a network that does not have ENS, you must pass in a normal Ethereum address. Check the value (with console.log) you pass into the kings that expect addresses, often the variable is null or the wrong type of object (not a string).